# How to load model attribute's with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to load a post's body (model's attribute) from ajax so the body can appear in a div when a button get's clicked. An option to possibly do this is by having a show page for each post that just gets inserted inside a div and has all of the information inside of it, but the show page already has different content than the one that has to be inserted inside the div. Would I have to load the attribute using a js.erb?

Also, already having the post's body on the page before hand is not an option because the bodies are very long and there could be multiple posts.

Comment: Given your stated constarints, ajax is the way to go. You do not *have* to use a `js.erb` file although that is certainly one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to load model attribute but I assume you are asking which is the most simple.  Using js.erb makes it really simple indeed.

1. put the codes from show page that will be reused to partial.  For example _object.html.erb
2. make your ajax call with datatype :script
   $.ajax({

   ```
      type: "GET",
      url: $(this).attr('href'),
      data: {
          object_id: object_id
      },
      dataType: "script",
      success: function () {
      }
   });
   ```
3. On the receiving side of ajax url, set the object and create js.erb file inside the view folders
4. render partial with escape javascript

> <%= escape_javascript(render(@obejct))%>